# MPLUS FIML: Why including binary-x variance changes the STDY estimates

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood, missing-data, binary-data, mplus

I have a model where I have missing values on binary-X.
When I want to use FIML to include all the missing cases, my STDY estimates (that I'm supposed to interpret as the X is binary) change into the STDYX, meaning that the estimate is not intuitively interpreted anymore as X can only be 0 or 1.

Is there another way to use FIML in MPLUS than adding the variance, as it seems a bit odd with binary variables?